# How do I ensure that each Change corresponds to its own Build?

Tags: continuous-integration, scheduler, buildbot

I have a buildbot 0.8.12 Scheduler configured as such:

`c['schedulers'].append(schedulers.SingleBranchScheduler(
                       name="all",
                       change_filter=util.ChangeFilter(branch='master'),
                       treeStableTimer=None,
                       builderNames=["runtests"]))`

My intention is to have it monitor the master branch (change_filter), and build each change as it comes in (treeStableTimer). When running, the Scheduler correctly picks up all the changes, but groups several Changes into a single Build instead of doing one Build per Change.

How can I force it to do one build per change? The [documentation for the SingleBranchScheduler](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#singlebranchscheduler) states that setting the `treeStableTimer` parameter to `None` should have achieved this, but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the 0.8.12 documentation. latest is for the next development branch.

http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.12/manual/cfg-builders.html#merging-build-requests